# ruby on rails: bundles like django?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

i wonder if ruby on rails have bundles, the ones similar in django?

kind of a plugin that contains css, js, images, ruby code and everything for one feature.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [Rails Engines](http://rails-engines.org/) tries to solve that problem

Answer (score 1):

You could use generators to copy CSS, JS and image files from a plugin to your application's public dir. For  models, controllers and the rest please see http://guides.rails.info/plugins.html

Comment: but i guess that is not the same thing?